# world_to_camera_view - returns same result if cube is rotated, not if camera is rotated

Tags: python

I'm expermenting with world_to_camera_view

`bpy_extras.object_utils.world_to_camera_view(scene, camera, co)`

Lets say I create a new blender file. I enter every point of a cube into this function and then paint the results.

Now I do the same thing again, but this time I rotate the cube.

I expect to get different sets of points, but I get the same points.

Now lets say I add a second cube at a different position. I expect again to get a different set of points. But again I get the same points (two sets of cubes on top of each other).

If I move the camera.. then I do get different points.

So my questions are: how can I use this to see two meshes? and why do I not see changes after a cube is moved, can I turn that on somehow?

Comment: quick guess: You use object space coordinates. You have to multiply your coordinates with the object's [world matrix](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7071/python-absolute-position-of-face/7072#7072) to get the world space coordinates which you pass to `world_to_camera_view`.

Comment: Even though this exact question wasn't asked before, this is really the same issue here: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/6155/55

Comment: Thank you this multiplying the word matrix coordinates was the exact solution. Yes I agree this is a duplicate and the answers detailed in the related question are very detailed.