# Bounding box of 3D object in 2D render is offset

Tags: python, rendering, scripting, coordinates

I am currently trying to translate a 3D object in my Blender scene to a region of interest in the respective 2D render. I have found these solutions [1](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/882/how-to-find-image-coordinates-of-the-rendered-vertex/38213), [2](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7198/save-the-2d-bounding-box-of-an-object-in-rendered-image-to-a-text-file), and [3](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7316/world-to-camera-view-returns-same-result-if-cube-is-rotated-not-if-camera-is?noredirect=1&lq=1) that make use of the [world_to_camera_view](https://github.com/dfelinto/blender/blob/master/release/scripts/modules/bpy_extras/object_utils.py) function within the bpy_extras.object_utils package. However, in my application, the region of interest is always offset slightly:
[image: 2D render mimicking depth camera]

The ROI (denoted by the blue square) should encompass the left hand. However, while it appears to be the right size, its position is offset.

Here is my script.

```
def camera_view_bounds_2d():
    scene = bpy.context.scene
    camera_object = scene.camera

    #focal object for region of interest, selected in UI
    mesh_object = bpy.data.objects[scene.Bounding_Box]

    x_pix_co = []
    y_pix_co = []

    verts = (vert.co for vert in mesh_object.data.vertices)
    for co in verts:
        world_co = mesh_object.matrix_world @ co
        co_2d = world_to_camera_view(scene, camera_object, world_co)

        render_scale = scene.render.resolution_percentage / 100
        render_size = (
            int(scene.render.resolution_x * render_scale),
            int(scene.render.resolution_y * render_scale),
        )

        x_pix_co.append(round(co_2d.x * render_size[0]))
        y_pix_co.append(round(co_2d.y * render_size[1]))
    
    min_x = min(x_pix_co)
    max_x = max(x_pix_co)
    min_y = min(y_pix_co)
    max_y = max(y_pix_co)
    
    print(f"the bounding box is ({min_x},{min_y}), ({max_x}, {max_y})")
```

It's worth noting that the hand is animated, and a track_to constraint has been applied to it to ensure that it is always in the view of the camera.

Comment: Recently answered something roundabouts similar here https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/214597/15543 in that the camera is being shifted to frame  ROI around OOI & to test created a 2D frame object as a visual. Can confirm the results (pre multiplication by pixels) are same.  Make sure you have same X & Y pixel aspect and ii) how are you positioning the ROI on the image?  My guess is that the unknown here is the issue, as what is "scene.bounding_Box" ... is it for example a sphere copy loc constrained to the hands vertex groups or a hand bone?

Comment: @batFINGER Thanks for the link, it looks like I might be able to modify your code to suit my needs. The X and Y aspect ratio (or height and width) are taken directly from the render image shape. The ROI is positioned with cv2 in a separate script using the values returned by the print statement: _print(f"the bounding box is ({min_x},{min_y}), ({max_x}, {max_y})")_

Comment: @batFINGER "scene.bounding_Box" is the [hand mesh](https://imgur.com/a/3rwsq7y) that I would like to calculate the bounding box for. I have [seperate empty object](https://imgur.com/a/lq4liNG) with a copy location constraint applied a bone in the hand mesh. This is what the camera is tracked to instead of the hand mesh itself because that origin is static.